# Should we write else statements in VHDL if/else blocks to handle things other than '0' and '1' for std_logic and std_logic_vectors?

Tags: vhdl

Which of these is correct way to write synthesis code?

This one:

```
  if EXPECTED_ACK_STATE_MATCHED(i) = '1' and EXPECTED_MSG_CODE_MATCHED(i) = '1' then
    EXTCMD_RESULT(i) <= CMD_EXECUTION_RESULT_IS_SUCCESS;
  elsif EXPECTED_ACK_STATE_MATCHED(i) = '1' and EXPECTED_MSG_CODE_MATCHED(i) = '0' then
    EXTCMD_RESULT(i) <= CMD_EXECUTION_RESULT_MSG_CODE_FAILED;
  elsif EXPECTED_ACK_STATE_MATCHED(i) = '0' and EXPECTED_MSG_CODE_MATCHED(i) = '1' then
    EXTCMD_RESULT(i) <= CMD_EXECUTION_RESULT_ACK_FAILED;
  elsif EXPECTED_ACK_STATE_MATCHED(i) = '0' and EXPECTED_MSG_CODE_MATCHED(i) = '0' then
    EXTCMD_RESULT(i) <= CMD_EXECUTION_RESULT_ACK_AND_MSG_CODE_FAILED;
  else -- deal with 'X', 'U' e.t.c.
    report "invalid condition occurred" severity failure
  end if;
```

Or this one:

```
      if EXPECTED_ACK_STATE_MATCHED(i) = '1' and EXPECTED_MSG_CODE_MATCHED(i) = '1' then
        EXTCMD_RESULT(i) <= CMD_EXECUTION_RESULT_IS_SUCCESS;
      elsif EXPECTED_ACK_STATE_MATCHED(i) = '1' and EXPECTED_MSG_CODE_MATCHED(i) = '0' then
        EXTCMD_RESULT(i) <= CMD_EXECUTION_RESULT_MSG_CODE_FAILED;
      elsif EXPECTED_ACK_STATE_MATCHED(i) = '0' and EXPECTED_MSG_CODE_MATCHED(i) = '1' then
        EXTCMD_RESULT(i) <= CMD_EXECUTION_RESULT_ACK_FAILED;
      else -- if EXPECTED_ACK_STATE_MATCHED(i) = '0' and EXPECTED_MSG_CODE_MATCHED(i) = '0' then
        EXTCMD_RESULT(i) <= CMD_EXECUTION_RESULT_ACK_AND_MSG_CODE_FAILED;
      end if;
```

I have written the condition matched in the else block explicitly to make reading the code easy.

Comment: These "values" exist only in simulation. If you don't handle them in simulation - nothing bad will happen as well, these will simply propagate to other signals making them "unknown" and such. Might be helpful for debugging though.

Comment: `else report` will generally be ignored in synthesis, and may catch faults in simulation. If you're using code coverage you may (should!) get coverage holes here, but your verification process should have ways to review and accept legitimate coverage holes.

Comment: How would an expert write the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference is to keep my synthesis code as simple as possible.   So I keep error checks as independent as practical from my logic code.   So I use choice number 2.

If I want error checks, I use an assert of the form (preferably concurrent, but in your case maybe sequential):

```
assert not (is_x(EXPECTED_ACK_STATE_MATCHED(i)) or is_x(EXPECTED_MSG_CODE_MATCHED(i))) report "invalid condition occurred" severity error
```

Answer (score 2):

Either of the ways you have written it is perfectly correct.

I don't believe that testing for values other than '0' or '1' is synthesizable in any devices I have ever used.  So it doesn't make any difference with regard to synthesis and implementation.

Testing for things like 'U' or 'X" can be useful for debug in simulation.  Its certainly not required, and I have always been able to debug my own code without adding such statements.